# Heroku Fixie Socks as own Proxy Socks5 Server

Tags: heroku, server, proxy, socks

I would like to make a Socks5 Proxy Server via Heroku and Fixie Socks addon.
Can you advice me how to do it. I do not get any idea yet.
I would like to connect my own socks5 proxy server with my PC/laptop/desktop, that I would make on heroku.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie-socks